# Xamarin.forms Stand-alone resource dictionaries don't update dynamically if there is no cs code behind file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin team introduced 2 different way of  [stand-alone-resource-dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries). Obviously there is a big difference but they neglected to write in their documentation.
Basically if i use  without cs code behind file and without x:class defined as defined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries) and referencing  like that in my page

`<ResourceDictionary Source="GradientStyles.xaml"/>`

GradientStyles.xaml look like below and i am updating GradientStartColor , GradientStopColor of PancakeView on runtime based on the theme selected.

```
    <pancakeView:GradientStopCollection x:Key="BackgroundGradientStops">
        <pancakeView:GradientStop Color="{StaticResource GradientStartColor}"
                                  Offset="0"/>
        <pancakeView:GradientStop Color="{StaticResource GradientStopColor}"
                                  Offset="0.74"/>
    </pancakeView:GradientStopCollection>
```

Implementation above just not working. It doesn't update Colors at all. 
The same exact code;

- Works in ContentPage.Resources directly. It will update
- Works if i define a stand-alone-resource-dictionary with cs code behind file and implement on the page like this below

> ```
>  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>         <resDics:GradientStyles  />
>   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
> ```

There is that annotation in the documentation but i don't get what exactly it means.

> This syntax doesnot instantiate the MyResourceDictionary class.
>   Instead, it references the XAML file.

Does it mean that it extends the contentpage using like partial class or inherits. Or is it cached only once and remains static? And when you use it with code behind class, it creates a new instance every time?
Finally is that a bug or feature? :)

Comment: You mean that you create new ResourceDictionary.xaml in project, then using this ResourceDictionary in ContentPage, it doesn't work? But I test [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/xaml-resourcedictionaries/), it works fine.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT yes correct. this sample looks similar. So if you change NormalTextColor on runtime. For example add a button there on the page and update NormalTextColor with another color, does it update the UI for you?

Comment: You mean that you have one Button in ContentPage, use one style in resourcedictionary, for example,changing background color or other color, now you assign another color for Button in ContentPage, yes it can update UI. If you set Button background directly, it will override the style setting.